# Querying the Username in a Share Data source (SSRS)

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I am running a project to go over all logins of all our SSRS 2012 datasources and I need a complete list of all datasources, INCLUDING the loginname used to connect. I couldn't find it anywhere.

I am convinced the datasource loginnames must be stored somewhere inside the database, or the RDL's themselves.

Does anyone have a clue how I can list all datasource login names of these  different datasources?

See attached pic for details:
[image: DataSource]

The Content column in Catalog table only contains the connection string and whether the data source is using Windows credentials (authentications) or not the username

```
SELECT SDS.name AS SharedDsName 
       ,SDS.[Path] 
       ,CONVERT(xml, CONVERT(varbinary(max), content)) AS DEF 
 FROM dbo.[Catalog] AS SDS 
 WHERE SDS.Type = 5
```

I did found the Username of the data source with this query :

```
select DSID, ItemID, SubscriptionID, Name, Extension, Link, 
CredentialRetrieval, Prompt, ConnectionString, 
OriginalConnectionString, OriginalConnectStringExpressionBased, 
UserName, Password, Flags, Version
FROM DataSource
```

But it's encrypted - not only the password is encrypted, but also the username itself.

I would appreciate a lead into the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Roni.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some further digging and came across this forum thread:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1312030-150-1.aspx

I created an RSS file with the content as explained in that thread (I removed some unnecessary columns).

I ran an in SSRS CLI    :

```
C:\> rs -i C:\Temp\FileName.rss -s <SERVER_NAME>/reportserver >c:\Temp\DataSources.txt
```

The generated text file included all the data sources information INCLUDING the username that is used for the stored credentials.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some digging, I doubt you'll be able to find an unencrypted list anywhere. It's storing it in the report server, so the SSRS engine is encrypting it on it's own; i.e it's generating a key and salt in the engine code and using it to encrypt\decrypt those columns. You won't be able to query it via T-SQL, but you might have better luck using PowerShell to parse through the HTML on the reporting front end.

I believe the tag in question is the value for input named "ui_txtStoredName". I attached a picture as an example.

[image: Example SSRS Data Source]